# How to modify file attributes without race conditions?

Tags: file, winapi, io, filesystems, nt

I want to modify a single attribute on a file (e.g the read-only attribute). In order to do that, it looks like I have to query the current file attributes with either `GetFileAttributes` or `GetFileInformationByHandle`, then set the new attributes with either `SetFileAttributes` or `SetFileInformationByHandle`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/retrieving-and-changing-file-attributes

However that is inherently racy, as the file attributes may change between the query and the update. Is there a method to update file attributes atomically? I would expect there to be an API like `ModifyFileAttributes(DWORD addAttributes, DWORD rmAttributes)` which would do its best to work atomically. Transactional NTFS is not an option for me because a) it's deprecated b) only works on NTFS.

Thanks!

Comment: "*Is there a method to update file attributes atomically?*" - AFAIK, no.

Comment: As [SetFileAttributesTransacted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfileattributestransactedw) said, *Many scenarios that TxF was developed for can be achieved through simpler and more readily available techniques. please see [Alternatives to using Transactional NTFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/deprecation-of-txf).* Like [FILE_SHARE_READ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT ah, true! If I deny write access by not passing FILE_SHARE_WRITE, then attributes cannot be changed. Nice! I thought FILE_SHARE_WRITE wasn't about attributes at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, [FILE_SHARE_READ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) is a trade-off. The following code is adapted from [SetFileInformationByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle#examples) function. *SetFileInformationByHandle* for hFile2 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tchar.h>
int main()
{
    //...
    HANDLE hFile1 = CreateFile(TEXT("tempfile"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);

    HANDLE hFile2 = CreateFile(TEXT("tempfile"),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ| FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hFile1 != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && hFile2 != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hFile = hFile1;
        //HANDLE hFile = hFile2;
        FILE_BASIC_INFO fdi{};
        fdi.FileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

        BOOL fResult = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile,
            FileBasicInfo,
            &fdi,
            sizeof(FILE_BASIC_INFO));

        if (fResult)
        {
            // File will be deleted upon CloseHandle.
            _tprintf(TEXT("SetFileInformationByHandle marked tempfile for deletion\n"));

            // ... 
            // Now use the file for whatever temp data storage you need,
            // it will automatically be deleted upon CloseHandle or 
            // application termination.
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("error %lu:  SetFileInformationByHandle could not mark tempfile for deletion\n"),
                GetLastError());
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        // At this point, the file is closed and deleted by the system.
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("error %lu:  could not create tempfile\n"),
            GetLastError());
    }
    //...
}
```